# NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/admin/ShutdownBroker

Tags: apache-kafka, noclassdeffounderror

When I run kafka broker shutdown from the provided shell file, there is a `NoClassDefFoundError` class exception, I don't know how to resolve it.
Please help.

command:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker --zookeeper 172.19.41.48:2181,172.19.41.50:2181,172.19.41.52:2181,172.19.41.55:2181,172.19.41.57:2181/huadong/kafka --broker 5 --num.retries 3 --retry.interval.ms 600
```

exception:

```
kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker --zookeeper 172.19.41.48:2181,172.19.41.50:2181,172.19.41.52:2181,172.19.41.55:2181,172.19.41.57:2181/huadong/kafka --broker 5 --num.retries 3 --retry.interval.ms 600
/export/servers/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/java -Xmx256M -server -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:bin/../config/tools-log4j.properties -cp .:/export/servers/jdk1.6.0_25/lib/dt.jar:/export/servers/jdk1.6.0_25/lib/tools.jar:bin/../core/build/dependant-libs-2.10.4*/*.jar:bin/../examples/build/libs//kafka-examples*.jar:bin/../contrib/hadoop-consumer/build/libs//kafka-hadoop-consumer*.jar:bin/../contrib/hadoop-producer/build/libs//kafka-hadoop-producer*.jar:bin/../clients/build/libs/kafka-clients*.jar:bin/../libs/jopt-simple-3.2.jar:bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.jar:bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1-javadoc.jar:bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1-scaladoc.jar:bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1-sources.jar:bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1-test.jar:bin/../libs/kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.16.jar:bin/../libs/lz4-1.2.0.jar:bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:bin/../libs/scala-library-2.11.5.jar:bin/../libs/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.2.jar:bin/../libs/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar:bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar:bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.1.6.jar:bin/../libs/zkclient-0.3.jar:bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:bin/../core/build/libs/kafka_2.10*.jar kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker --zookeeper 172.19.41.48:2181,172.19.41.50:2181,172.19.41.52:2181,172.19.41.55:2181,172.19.41.57:2181/huadong/kafka --broker 5 --num.retries 3 --retry.interval.ms 600
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/admin/ShutdownBroker
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker.  Program will exit.
```

CLASSPATH:

`[admin@A06-R12-302F0402-I36-59 kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1]$ echo $CLASSPATH
.:/export/servers/jdk1.7.0_71/lib/dt.jar:/export/servers/jdk1.7.0_71/lib/tools.jar:/export/servers/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1/libs/*`

Comment: Check your `classpath` (f.e. output it to the log or screen), this error most probably due to class path issue.

Comment: You should use `/path/*` or `/path/concretelib.jar` instead of `path/*.jar` when set classpath value

Comment: I add my *classpath* in the question. I use /path/*, but still error: Error: Could not find or load main class kafka.admin.ShutdownBroker

Answer (score 0):

Kafka developers removed helper tool to initiate graceful broker shutdown as per discussion in the ticket [KAFKA-1298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1298) ([removal commit](https://github.com/apache/kafka/commit/d0df33df3df314ccd42f700a592e8efc31e80f87), documentation [page diff](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/diffpagesbyversion.action?pageId=31819985&selectedPageVersions=30&selectedPageVersions=29)).

Now only supported way to gracefully shutdown broker is by sending `SIGTERM` signal to broker process:
this initiate logs syncing to disk and start reelection of new partition leaders for which current broker was a leader.

Easiest way to stop broker gracefully now is to use `kafka-server-stop.sh` script provided as part of Kafka distribution.

Configuration options which affect this behavior:

- `controlled.shutdown.enable`
- `controlled.shutdown.max.retries`
- `controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms`